# Nodejs Request values

Tags: json, node.js, express, webserver

So I have a nodejs server and I am trying to make comparisons to the req values. Firstly, here is my code:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    firstName = req.body.firstName;
    lastName = req.body.lastName;
    message = req.body.message;
    token = req.body.token;
    user = {name: firstName + " " + lastName, token: token};
    selectedUser = req.body.selectedUser;
    users.push(user);
    console.log(user.name);

    if (req.body.isAndroid === true) {
        sendToAndroid(); //add message parameter
    } else {
        sendToios(); //add message parameter
    }
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('running on port 8080');
});
```

---

```
//GCM
function sendToAndroid() {
    var message = new gcm.Message();
    var tokenLocation;
    //API Server Key
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyD-B3EG1xpMh6YhwBKfLMyw0GIQKWfGgZM');

    //console.log(message);
    // Value the payload data to send...
    message.addData({
        title: 'Hello',
        body: 'Message From: ' + user.name + ': ' + message,
        msgcnt: 1,
        timeToLive: 3000 
    });

    // At least one reg id required
    if (registrationToken.indexOf(token) == -1) {
        registrationToken.push(token);
        tokenLocation = registrationToken.indexOf(token);
    } else {
        tokenLocation = registrationToken.indexOf(token);
    }

    if (users.indexOf(user.name) == -1) {
        console.log("user destination not found");
    } else {
        var userTokenArray = [];
        userTokenArray.push(user.token);
        sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: userTokenArray } , function (err, response) {
            if(err) console.error(err);
            else    console.log(response);    
        });
        userTokenArray.pop();
    }

}
```

And here is my problem when outputting to see what the value is:

```
running on port 8080
undefined undefined
user destination not found
```

What I am trying to do is put the registered users into an array of users that each element has a full name and token. Then in the Android function, it will check to see what value value is selected and then push a notification to the selectedUser via their token. I am so confused on how to compare the "strings" or whatever they are. I am using nodejs express with body-parser.

Comment: I guess my first question is what prints that "undefined undefined" line? Doesn't look like this `console.log(user.name);` is doing it, given there is 2 undefined words there. Probably make your `console.log` statements a bit more unique.

Comment: Sorry. It is printing undefined undefined because I am sending a firstName and lastName and console.log(user.name) should print name from the user. Which is from the variable on line 6 with first and last name appended to it

Comment: A strange thing is that token is able to output properly. but names and message and selectedUser is not able to printed

Comment: if `req.body.firstName;` is undefined then you might want to look at how you are calling the endpoint. How are you doing this?

Comment: You should show where you are using `body-parser` (and which of its middleware you are using) in relation to your route handler. Also you should show *how* you are making the requests to your Express server (e.g. the html and/or javascript or whatever client code).